# Androidx SearchView Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.setOnQueryTextListener

Tags: java, android

MainActivityCustonlistViewnew.java
Error comes with this line  :  searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_option,menu);
        MenuItem menuItem=menu.findItem(R.id.search);
        SearchView searchView=(SearchView)menuItem.getActionView();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
```

This is my XML Search_Option.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:apps="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <item android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="Search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        apps:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

Mylog cat

````
        at com.seamans.marina.MainActivityCustonlistViewnew.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivityCustonlistViewnew.java:75)
        at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:3481)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:325)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:94)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$AppCompatWindowCallback.onCreatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:2830)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:94)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.ToolbarActionBar.populateOptionsMenu(ToolbarActionBar.java:455)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.ToolbarActionBar$1.run(ToolbarActionBar.java:56)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)```
````

Comment: `apps:actionViewClass` – Change that prefix to `app`. Your `apps` prefix is mapped to a namespace that's usually denoted by the `tools` prefix, which is for attributes that only apply during design, not at runtime.

Comment: yes boss but when changing it to app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />  : it says unresolve SearchView

Comment: and unresolve package widget

Comment: to resolve it add proper support library in your gradle file.

Comment: Yeah, right. From your previous question, you're using androidx, so change that class name to `androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView`. And make sure that you have that class imported in your code, too, instead of `android.widget.SearchView`.

Comment: can you please show me which support library should i add?  this is my gradle file ```implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01' //this is android x
    implementation "com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:6.1.2"```

Comment: waaaahhhhhhhh....what happened?? error comes : ```CONFIGURE FAILED in 311ms
Supplied String module notation 'androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView' is invalid. Example notations: 'org.gradle:gradle-core:2.2', 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5:javadoc'.```

Comment: You don't need to change anything except the files you posted snippets from above. Undo whatever you changed in the file that is giving that error.

Comment: ok thanks i'll try again. thanks

Comment: i've undo it , i have notice that ```import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;``` is already imported but same error comes when running it to emulator.

Comment: @AiexaAlexander  i missed androidx library in title  @MikeM is right. You just need to change `apps:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"` to `app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"` and @MikeM  kindly post as answer :)

Comment: yahoo!!!...it worked!..thank you very much guys! you helped me alot.